# Get calling file name from include()

Tags: php, include, include-path, magic-constants

I want to get the name of the file that includes another file from inside the included file.

I know there is the `__FILE__` magic constant, but that doesn't help, since it returns the name of the *included* file, not the *including* one.

Is there any way to do this? Or is it impossible due to the way PHP is interpreted?

Comment: Jon I think Theraot's answer is much more on point. But thanks for getting the ball rolling. Made my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually just a special case of what PHP templating engines do. Consider having this function:

```
function ScopedInclude($file, $params = array())
{
    extract($params);
    include $file;
}
```

Then `A.php` can include `C.php` like this:

```
<?php
// A.php
ScopedInclude('C.php', array('includerFile' => __FILE__));
```

Additionally, `B.php` can include `C.php` the same way without trouble.

```
<?php
// B.php
ScopedInclude('C.php', array('includerFile' => __FILE__));
```

`C.php` can know its includer by looking in the $params array.

```
<?php
// C.php
echo $includerFile;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly how I needed it to. The reason I picked this over @wedgwood's is for the simplicity of expandability. Thanks again.

Comment: Googlers, don't miss @Theraot's [fantastic solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125864/1479945), which _doesn't require any change_ in the including script!

Comment: @Sz. Thanks for the stear. EXACTLY what I was looking for. Does PHP 7 introduce a simpler way of doing this? I would have thought this would be useful in all sorts of places.

Answer (score 32):

So this question is pretty old, but I was looking for the answer and after leaving here unsatisfied, I came across `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];`  Of course this works if the php file doing the including is a web page.

This gives you the full path of the "including file" on the server.  eg /var/www/index.php. so if you want just the filename, eg index.php, you will need to use basename() eg

`basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`

So, if in your index.php you have the following line:

`<?php include("./somephp.php"); ?>`

and in somephp.php you have

`echo "this is the file that included me: " . basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`

you will get

`this is the file that included me: index.php`

output to the browser. This also works if the user is accessing your file without explicitly including the filename in the url, eg `www.example.com` instead of  `www.example.com/index.php`.

Answer (score 9):

### Solution

Knowing that the functions used to include files are `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once`, also knowing that they are reserved words in PHP, meaning that it will not be possible to declare user functions with the same name, and based on [wedgwood's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10265300/402022) of using `debug_backtrace` you can actually work out from what file the include was called.

What we are going to do is iterate over the backtrace untill we find the most recent call to any of the four include functions, and the the file where it was called. The following code demostrate the technique:

```
function GetIncludingFile()
{
    $file = false;
    $backtrace =  debug_backtrace();
    $include_functions = array('include', 'include_once', 'require', 'require_once');
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($backtrace); $index++)
    {
        $function = $backtrace[$index]['function'];
        if (in_array($function, $include_functions))
        {
            $file = $backtrace[$index]['file'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $file;
}
```

The above code will return the absolute path of the file where the last include happened, if there hasn't been any include it will return false. Note that the file may has been include from a file that was included from another file, the above function only works for the deepest include.

With a simple modification, you can also get the last included file:

```
function GetIncludedFile()
{
    $file = false;
    $backtrace =  debug_backtrace();
    $include_functions = array('include', 'include_once', 'require', 'require_once');
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($backtrace); $index++)
    {
        $function = $backtrace[$index]['function'];
        if (in_array($function, $include_functions))
        {
            $file = $backtrace[$index - 1]['file'];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $file;
}
```

---

### Observations

Note that `__FILE__` is not the included file, but the current file. For example:

file A.php:

```
<?php
    function callme()
    {
        echo __FILE__;
    }
?>
```

file B.php:

```
<?php
    include('A.php');
    callme();
?>
```

file index.php:

```
<?php
    include('B.php');
?>
```

In the above example, in the context of the file B.php the included file is B.php (and the including file is index.php) but the output of the function `callme` is the path of A.php because `__FILE__` is in A.php.

---

Also note that `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will give the the absolute path to the script requested by the client. If `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] == __FILE__` it means that the current file is the requested one, and therefore there *probably* hasn't been any includes...

The above method checks if the current file is the requested one, but not if it hasn't been included (below is an example of how the requested file can be included). An actual solution to check if there has not been any inclusions could be to check `count(get_included_files()) == 1`.

---

The requested file can be an included file in the following way:

file x.php

```
<?php
   $var = 'something';
   include('index.php');
?>
```

file index.php

```
<?php
    if (!isset($var))
    {
        include('x.php');
        exit;
    }
    echo 'something';
?>
```

In the above example, the file index.php will include x.php, then x.php will include index.php back, afterwards index.php outputs "something" and returns control to x.php, x.php returns control to index.php and it reaches exit;

This shows that even if index.php was the requested script, it was also included from another script.

Comment: It would be awesome to get more info on the debug_backtrace() and it's performance characteristics.

Comment: @MrMesees You can have a look at the [PHP source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c). It appears to have linear complexity with respect to the depth of the call stack, and populating objects and argument have extra cost.

Comment: F***** genius! I could only upvote by one but please feel like I have given u ten. Just PERFECT!!!!!! (Sorry getting a bit over excited here!)

Answer (score 5):

I can't find the easy way to cover this.
But If the including one is really important to you, you could hack it with some global variable and your own include function.

e.g.

```
<?php                                                                            

    $g_including_files = array();                                                    

    function my_include($file) {                                                     
        $bt =  debug_backtrace();

        global $g_including_files;                                                   
        $g_including_files[basename($file)] = $bt[0]['file']; 
        return include($file);                                                                                                                                                                     
    }
```

May that be helpful for you :)

Comment: you were on the right track... I have a working solution based on your idea (exactly one year after): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16125864/402022

Answer (score -1):

This works!

Include this in the file being called.

```
$includedFiles = get_included_files();
$currentFile = realpath(__FILE__);

$callerFile = '';
$backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);

foreach ($backtrace as $trace) {
    if (isset($trace['file']) && realpath($trace['file']) !== $currentFile) {
        $callerFile = $trace['file'];
        break;
    }
}

if (!empty($callerFile)) {
    echo 'Included by: ' . $callerFile. '</br>';
} else {
    echo 'No direct inclusion found.';
}
```

Comment: Your chat GPT tried to plagiarize this code from the answer on THIS EXACT PAGE but AS USUAL did it WRONG

Comment: also you should never post a code that you don't understand