# Name of the file included into

Tags: php

I know that sounds confusing, but how do you find the name of the file that another file is included into.

For example, I have two files a.php and b.php.  b.php is included into a.php like so:

a.php:

```
include('b.php');
```

Now I want code to put into b.php to find the name of a.php.  Does that make any sense?

EDIT: Ok, I have come up with a better way to rephrase the question:

How do you get the name of the including file (so in the above example, find the name of file a.php using code in b.php).  Does this work?

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Comment: Define further details, what u want?

Comment: Maybe explain __why__ you want this as well, as it sounds like a strange thing to need to do, there's _probably_ a better way.

Comment: I think this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265216/get-calling-file-name-from-include might interest you.

Comment: I have a program that updates an sql database and after its done redirect the user to the form page.  There are multiple form pages and so I need a dynamic link to each one of them.  Does that make sense, its kind of hard to explain?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you might need it but it's possible using global `__FILE__` constant:

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) about `__FILE__`:

> The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, **FILE** always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some circumstances.

Comment: I think that he wants to know who included `b.php`. Using `__FILE__` in `b.php` will return the full path to `b.php`. As I said in my comment to his question, this has already been solved in an other question (considering I get what he asked :D)

Comment: @Brice ... and this path has all necessary info to be extracted with `pathinfo` or `basename` functions.

Comment: This is the reverse of what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want

```
http://in1.php.net/get_included_files
```

try this function at end.