# Use php file from other directory and include file from current directory

Tags: php

Suppose, we have three directories `A`, `B` and `C` along with another `engine` directory.

Now I want to post a search query via POST request to `../engine/search.php` in the index file of A, B and C, but tell the file `search.php` to include the `config.php` file from the respective directory (with different parameters for the search). I.e. I cannot simply include `../[A,B,C]/config.php` in `engine/search.php` since it depends on where the search is called from.

Is there any way to do this without having to keep a separate copy of `search.php` in each directory and thus including directly the config file from the respective directory? This should be possible, since similar multisite PHP setups exists (e.g. Wordpress MU).

Maybe something like `__DIR__` that would give the path of where the php file gets called from rather than where it is located.

For security reasons, I do not want to pass the paths as part of the post request.

Comment: Why does including the config depend on where the search is called from?  I guess I don't really understand what you're trying to do here or why you can't just specify the PHP file you want to include.

Comment: search.php needs to read from config.php. Now I want to reuse this search.php in another directory which has different parameters in config.php

Comment: You could include a hidden field in the search form which indicates what type of search it is.  Then the server-side code could use that field as a flag to determine which file to include.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but it is not so nice, since I´d have to change search.php each time I want to reuse it from another directory. Anyway, I'm upvoting your suggestion :)

Comment: Why would you need to change it?  It can just have a simple `if` statement or `switch` statement of some kind to determine which dependent file to include.  That's your goal, isn't it?  To conditionally include a different file depending on some indicator?  So why can't a hidden field be that indicator?

Comment: So you're suggesting to pass just the relative path part as some kind of a flag?

Comment: Well, not the actual path of course.  Allowing users to control what files you load would be a security risk.  But an indicator of some sort, which your server-side code would check and then use the known path for that indicator.  Something as simple as a name for the search would do the trick.

Comment: So I would still have to update the name to path mapping each time. I was hoping there is some other less hacky / more cannonical way to do it.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to write a few lines of code to determine which file to include.  If you're trying to do this *without writing any code* then that's not going to work very well.

Comment: Are you familiar with router libraries? Like this one https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute ? They might help you in this situation. You necessarily do not need to put your files in actual directories `A`, `B` and `C`. If you're good with @David solution, then you might want too write some code to use some sort of directory mapping, and only update that mapping each time.

Comment: Not really, but researching on this brought me to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265216/get-calling-file-name-from-include which is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some comments on the question clarifying what you're attempting...

One thing you can do is to include a hidden field in your search forms indicating what "type" of search it is.  Something as simple as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="SearchType" value="SearchA" />
```

Then in your server-side code you can determine which file to include based on that value.  Something like this:

```
switch ($_POST["SearchType"]) {
    case "SearchA":
        include("../A/config.php");
        break;
    case "SearchB":
        include("../B/config.php");
        break;
    // etc.
}
```

That way the config is determined dynamically by the form being posted, and not relying on any state tracked server-side about the form which was previously loaded.

Comment: btw, breaks are missing ;)