# Page title says "navbar" instead of the page title

Tags: php, html

I've found a couple of "fixes" on this site, none of which have worked for myself.

The code I am using is `<title><?php echo ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));?> | Test</title>` which is in a file called `navbar.php`.

To link the navbar.php file to the actual page being used, I am using the following in [page name].php:

`<div id="navbar"></div>`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#navbar").load("navbar");
    });
</script>
```

Which places the code from navbar.php into the current page.

The issue is that the title says `Navbar | [website name]` instead of `[page name] | [website name]`

Marking this question as a duplicate is invalid as the other questions do not contain what I am asking nor do they have an answer that works for my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get calling file name from include()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265216/get-calling-file-name-from-include)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get filename of file which ran PHP include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393145/get-filename-of-file-which-ran-php-include)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTTP_REFERER instead of PHP_SELF as follows. Because PHP_SELF will give the name of the callee file while the HTTP_REFERER gives you the caller file name. As you are interested in the caller name on the title this is the right way

```
<title><?php echo ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));?> | Test</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove title tag from navbar.php
Check the following for the same

navbar.php

```
    <p>Text or content you want to load in page title</p>
```

pagetitle.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><?php echo ucfirst(pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME));?> | Website Name</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="navbar"></div>
        </body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#navbar").load("navbar.php");
            });
        </script>
    </html>
```